How to shorten vertical distance between epigraphs?
The format \epigraph{Quote}{Reference} does not function well in the context, because of the text needed in Reference.
So how may one shorten the distance between the two epigraphs in the following document?
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\setlength{\epigraphrule}{0pt}

\begin{document}

    \setlength{\epigraphwidth}{0.69\textwidth}
    \epigraph{\emph{``Mathematics, rightly viewed, 
    possesses not only truth, but supreme beauty \ldots''}}
    
    \setlength{\epigraphwidth}{0.59\textwidth}
    \epigraph{Bertrand Russell, in \ldots}

\end{document}


Off topic, in general, the author name followed by the epigraph text, should be in flushright position, and the tag is \epigraph{...text...}{...author name...}

Note: \epigraph has two mandatory arguments (see section 2.1 of the documentation). Don't try to use it with only one. Can you explain, why you cannot use \epigraph{Text}{Source}, maybe adding an example, that shows why you can't. Without I guess you are searching something like https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/444262/277964 or https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/657885/277964

@cabohah Does this explain it?  \setlength{\epigraphwidth}{0.69\textwidth}
\epigraph{\emph{``Mathematics, rightly viewed,
possesses not only truth, but supreme beauty \ldots''}}{How may one obtain the author name and references in such a format that the last line adjusts leftwards, and not rightwards as here?}
\setlength{\epigraphwidth}{0.59\textwidth}
\epigraph{Bertrand Russell, in \ldots}

This is rather an indication that it is an XY problem and you actually want to know how the source can be indented more than the text. If I am not mistaken, there is already another question for this, which was either based on a redefinition of \@episource or (which would be more recommended) \sourceflush.

Let's look how \epigraph is defined:
\newcommand{\epigraph}[2]{%
  \vspace{\beforeepigraphskip}
  \vbox{%
    \epigraphsize
    \begin{\epigraphflush}
    \begin{minipage}{\epigraphwidth}
      \@epitext{#1}\\
      \@episource{#2}%
    \end{minipage}%
    \end{\epigraphflush}%
  }%
  \nointerlineskip
  \vspace*{\afterepigraphskip}%
  \ifepigraphnoindent\@afterheading\fi
}

Quite a lot of things, but not difficult to understand:

the command has two arguments (you're using just one!);

it should be issued between paragraphs;

it produces a \vbox in which \epigraphsize is stated (default \small)

the \vbox contains an \epigraphflush environment (default flushright);

this environment contains a minipage of size \epigraphwidth;

the minipage contains two “lines”, one is \@epitext{#1} and the other is `@episource{#2};

the environment is closed and the \vbox finished up; no vertical space due to the standard interline skip calculation and a fixed \afterepigraphskip vertical space;

at the end, code related to the \epigraphnoindent choice.


Thus you want to see what \@epitext does, namely,
\newcommand{\@epitext}[1]{%
  \begin{minipage}{\epigraphwidth}\begin{\textflush} #1\\
    \ifdim\epigraphrule>\z@ \@epirule \else \vspace*{1ex} \fi
  \end{\textflush}\end{minipage}}

This uses a minipage with \epigraphwidth horizontal size, containing a \textflush environment (default flushleft) and ends a paragraph, leaving a vertical space of 1ex, unless the rule is wanted.
Similarly, here's \@episource
\newcommand{\@episource}[1]{%
  \begin{minipage}{\epigraphwidth}\begin{\sourceflush} #1\end{\sourceflush}
  \end{minipage}}

which uses a \sourceflush environment, default flushright.
What you want is to use \itshape in \@epitext and flushleft also in \@episource, but also to remove the vertical space.
In my opinion, the minipage produced by \@epitext should be [b] vertically aligned and similarly \@episource should have `[t]. Thus standard interline space would be computed.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{epigraph}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@epitext}[1]{%
  \begin{minipage}[b]{\epigraphwidth}\begin{\textflush} \itshape #1% added \itshape
%    \ifdim\epigraphrule>\z@ \@epirule \else \vspace*{1ex} \fi % <--- removed
  \end{\textflush}\end{minipage}}
\renewcommand{\@episource}[1]{%
  \begin{minipage}[t]{\epigraphwidth}\begin{\sourceflush} #1\end{\sourceflush}
  \end{minipage}}
\makeatother

\renewcommand{\sourceflush}{flushleft}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\epigraphwidth}{0.69\textwidth}
\epigraph{``Mathematics, rightly viewed,
  possesses not only truth, but supreme beauty \ldots''}
{Bertrand Russell, in \ldots}

\end{document}



That's interesting! BTW, I just posted another epigraph question; it includes an incidental uncertainty concerning how to formulate questions more appropriately here.

@FrodeAlfsonBjørdal The new question with \cite is completely unreadable. By the way, you use none of the suggested methods, as far as I can see.

IMHO you don't want to reduce the distance between two epigraphs, but use a different format for the source, for example:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\setlength{\epigraphrule}{0pt}
\renewcommand*{\sourceflush}{reducedleft}
\newenvironment{reducedleft}{%
  \trivlist \raggedright \setlength{\itemindent}{.1\textwidth} \item \relax
}{\endtrivlist}
\newenvironment{italicleft}{\flushleft\itshape}{\endflushleft}
\renewcommand{\textflush}{italicleft}
\setlength{\epigraphwidth}{0.69\textwidth}

\begin{document}

\epigraph{``Mathematics, rightly viewed, 
  possesses not only truth, but supreme beauty \ldots''}{Bertrand Russel,
  in \ldots}
    
\end{document}


Please also note: You should always use the mandatory second argument of \epigraph, even if a epigraph has no source. In this case use an empty argument. Using \epigraph with only one mandatory argument would instead read the next token as second mandatory argument and therefore can break your code.

Thanks! I now articulated my real problem (which made me tru two epigraphs) more precisely in a new question here:  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/725004/how-may-source-text-after-epigraph-text-be-left-justified
