How may source text, after epigraph text, be left justified?
The question is more precisely articulated in the following MWE:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\setlength{\epigraphrule}{0pt}

\begin{document}
    
    \setlength{\epigraphwidth}{0.69\textwidth}
    \epigraph{\emph{``Mathematics, rightly viewed, possesses not only truth, 
but supreme beauty \ldots''}}{How may one obtain the author name and 
references in such a format that the last line adjusts leftwards, and not 
rightwards as here?}
    
\end{document}


You can redefine \sourceflush to use environment flushleft instead of the default flushright:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\setlength{\epigraphrule}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\sourceflush}{flushleft}
\begin{document}
    
    \setlength{\epigraphwidth}{0.69\textwidth}
    \epigraph{\emph{``Mathematics, rightly viewed, 
            possesses not only truth, but supreme beauty \ldots''}}{How may one obtain the author 
name and references in such a format that the last line adjusts leftwards, and not rightwards
 as here?}
    
\end{document}


See the documentation of epigraph section 2.3 for more information (and for an example also using flushleft).
BTW: For separation of contents and formatting it would be better to set \epigraphwidth in the document preamble if this width should be used for all epigraphs.
